# What goes into making a good automatic transmission software?

Tags: software, transmission

I was recently taught how an automatic transmission works (at least the main principle) and although very pleased of my new knowledge, I am now left with another unanswered question: how does the software controlling the transmission work?

Well I know that it takes into consideration inputs such as engine speed, gas pedal and driving mode ("comfort", "sport", "economy"...) but how are these inputs treated? Is it just plain conditional decisions such as "if engine speed is below 3000 RPM and gas pedal is over 70%, drop a gear" or is there some kind of mathematical model involved?

And finally: what makes one automatic transmission better than another?

Comment: "*what makes one automatic transmission better than another?*" Perhaps you should instead ask what are the performance criteria of an automatic transmission? If it did just use simple thresholding, there would be hysteresis but I doubt this is the case. With all the effort put into building the engine, the manufacturers should the engine's power curves which means it wouldn't be that much more effort to let the computer know them too. Theoretically, you could make it to operate at the point of best efficiency at constant speed but at max power when sufficiently accelerating.

Comment: Yes my last question is a bit misleading. "I thought it was only the engine RPM that mattered" well yes but not only. Let's say you are cruising at 2000 RPM and you suddenly floor the gas pedal : you would expect the transmission to drop one or two gears to make for a better acceleration (at least that is how most "modern" automatic transmissions behave)

Comment: Yeah I retracted that after sitting back and thinking about it for 5 seconds. Not from experience though because no car I've driven so far seems to do that.

Comment: If you think you know how autos work, then critique this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kLBe7CFWT3A&t=3s. But there are autos now with 6, 7 or 8 or more speeds that will drop 2 or 3 gears if full acceleration is demanded - the ecu will also cut the a/c and the alternator to give max power to the wheels... The info is based on a characteristic map and if you want to follow those then Bosch did soem very good info way back with the J and K Jetronic systems. Well worth reading as they nail the basics.

Comment: Prior to the inclusion of computer controlled devices on cars, automatic transmissions were all mechanical, there was no computer software.

Comment: @Fred analog & logic circuitry has no software, but I wouldn't call it mechanical

Comment: @Abel before electronic circuitry an automatic transmission did all logic using the transmission oil in a fluid logic circuit. I would call that mechanical.

Comment: @Abel There exists more possibilities for commutation than  circuits. Among things like mechanical gears and such there are also pneumatic and hydraulic methods. There are pneumatic computers in some places because electronic circuitry can't survive the environmental conditions (sometimes as mundane as high humidity). I am not necessarily saying a transmission uses these but they exist.

Answer (score 0):

A control system is a setup for getting the desired outputs for a set of inputs.  In this case inputs are driver's body and output is the motion of the vehicle.  Constraints for a drive by wire system include the need to be similar enough to current automobiles such that a person that passed a driving exam with a different car could reasonably be expected to drive it with a quick glance at the manual.  There are also requirements for safety regarding things like braking and going into neutral even if the vehicle were damaged/inoperable to a degree.

Desired can be varied as some people prefer the feel of certain vehicles.  Naturally there's a trade off between that feel and other important factors like fuel efficiency.  Ultimately it comes down to translating human to machine.  Machine tends to be capable of doing a lot more compared to the ability for a human to produce exact specifications on the fly.  This is part of why we use a combination of modes to provide context and quickly adjustable realtime input to issue immediate objectives.

There is absolutely a mathematical model involved- one including the model of the vehicle (including the software for the automatic gear shifting) and probably also a model of a driver for input.  Things like driver wanting to go from 0 to 100 kmph getting on a highway, wanting to stop after seeing an obstacle on the road, and many other scenarios should be simulated.  Simulations in turn produce expected metrics like stopping distance and fuel consumption/efficiency.  Designs that fail to get the necessary results are tweaked and re-run  without having to build a physical vehicle just to rule out a design.

As for the workings of the algorithms, that depends on what needs to be translated or achieved and what is available to achieve them.  For example some light vehicles at least partially fake low gear; the setting still means "I'm trying to move something heavy rather than go really fast when I step on the gas" but it may translate to fuel flow control and not going into higher gear rather than shifting to a nonexistent lower gear.  This way the capability is provided (to also not speed off into oblivion should the load suddenly detach) but with poor fuel efficiency.  Standard automatic drive setting has to weigh responding quickly against fuel efficiency, likely incorporating not just position but also things that may indicate urgency like rate of pedals all while providing a consistent feel so that a driver can learn to reliably and safely maneuver the vehicle.

Comment: Thanks for the detailled reply. Unfortunately it does not fully answer my initial question as I am more interested in how these algorithms and models are implemented (a concrete detailled example or a scientific paper of some sort would be ideal). Your answer still enlightens a few ideas that I did not originaly think about such as fuel efficiency and similarity between different system implementations.

Comment: Try searching the nets for "automobile plant model" and go from there.  You can search for papers on modeling steel structures, bolts, tires, engines, etc.  Cars at some level are masses that forces can accelerate.

Answer (score 0):

In reality they are more complex than this but here's a shift map.
[image: shift schedule]

So if you were to accelerate from a standstill at 50% throttle you'd change from 1 to 2 at 40 kph, and then up through 2 and 3 to point A, at 100 kph, 50% throttle, you'd be in 4th, and as you come off the throttle it changes to 5th and then 6th, to get you to point B. If you then add throttle at 41% it'll change back down to 5th. Of course in reality you'll be changing speed as well if you use different throttle settings.